# How to run a python script 10 times per second

Tags: python-2.7, unix

I have a python script and i want to run that script say test.py 10 times per second.

I know how to run script after specific interval, but i want to run that script number of times per second.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use time and while loop as following:

```
import time

TIMES = 10


def main():
    pass
    # your code here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_start = time.time()

    # run main() function TIMES times in 1 sec.
    i = 0
    while True:
        time_current = time.time()
        if time_current > time_start + i / float(TIMES):
            print('{}: {}'.format(i, time_current))
            main()
            i += 1
        if i > 9:
            break
```

FYI.